# Set the min date of Telerik Datepicker on onChange event of another Telerik datepicker in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I am doing project in `ASP.NET MVC3` with `C#`.

I am using telerik `Datepicker.`

On change event of One datepicker, I want to set minDate of another datepicker.

and wants to do this in `javascript`.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ViewModel>" %> 
.
.                                                                                                                                         
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
                            </div>                     
                            <div class="editor-field">                               
                                       <%: Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.StartDate).ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("OnChangeDatePicker")))%>                                                                            
                            </div>
.
.
```

I tried something like this:

```
function OnChangeDatePicker(e) {
    var d = new Date(e.date);
    StartDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    var datePicker = $("#ApprovalDate").data("tDatePicker");
    var minDate = new Date(StartDate);
    minDate.setDate(StartDate);
    datePicker.min(minDate);  
}
```

But it is giving me error that `datepicker.min()` is not valid.

This function will be called on OnChange event of `"StartDate"` datepicker.

In this function, I want to set minDate of `"ApprovalDate"` datepicker which will be date in StartDate datepicker.

I want some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the following demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/clientsideapi

There is button which says "Set Min Date". so this will set Min date of another date picker. Basically the controls have a rich client side API. so you need to use the right methods to work with the controls from client side.

So here is the JavaScript code to set Min Date on a date picker control:

```
function getDatePicker() 
{            
var datePicker = $('#DatePicker').data("tDatePicker");            
return datePicker;        
}

function minDatePicker() 
{            
var value = $('#DatePickerMinOrMax').data("tDatePicker").value();            
getDatePicker().min(value);        
}
```

In the above code - DatePicker is the main control on which I want to set a min date. DatePickerMinorMax is another date picker which is used to select min or max date.

If you take a look at the demo - demo is self explanatory

Comment: I refered this demo. but am setting min date on the OnChange event of another datepicker.I tried it but is giving me error: `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'min': object is null or undefined`

Comment: I already posted my function, sorry sir but which code u want??

Comment: i meant your complete ASPX code ... hard to work with bits and pieces

Comment: I can't post my complete code but I posted my .ascx's datepicker on which am calling the function. Thank you